# Какая директива для Google заменяет директиву Clean-param в Яндексе

Tags: seo, индексация, поисковые-системы, robots.txt

Доброго времени суток.

Есть задача закрыть от индексации в `Google` и `Яндекс` след. ссылки

```
...blog/?year=2021
...blog/?year=2022
...blog/?year=2016
```

Если параметр Get не меняет содержимое страницы, Яндекс рекомендует использовать директиву `Clean-param`и я добавил в роботс след. строку

```
Clean-param: year /
```

Но как я понимаю, это правило не распространяется на боты Google.

Как дать понять Гуглу, что все страницы с параметром `year`нужно закрыть от индексации и нужно ли добавить к строке User-agent։ Yandex?

```
User-agent։ Yandex
Clean-param: year /
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте link rel="[canonical](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls?hl=ru)" для указания канонического адреса.